# zend validator Zend_Validate_EmailAddress does nothing: site config looks OK, but probably isn't

Tags: zend-framework, zend-validate

Baffled again. (Zend Framework 1.11.1)

I've just added a validator to a VERY simple form, and nothing happens when invalid data is entered.

The code:

```
    $form = new Zend_Form;
    $form->setAction('/MyController/reponsepage')
           ->setMethod('post');
    $form->setAttrib('id', 'firstTestForm');
    $form->addElement('text', 'email', array('label' => 'EMail', 'value' => $this->_user['email']));
    $form->addElement('hidden', 'expertID', array('value' => $_targetExpertID));
  $form->addElement('submit', 'Submit and Be Free!');
  $v = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
  $v->setMessage('Please enter a valid email address.');
  $mailElem = $form->getElement('email')
      ->addValidator($v)
      ->setRequired(true);

    $this->view->form = $form;
```

setRequired seems to do nothing. Leaving the field empty and hitting submit goes right through.
Garbage data also goes right through.

**No error messages, nothing.**

The library directory contains:

```
PATH_BLAH\library\Zend\Validate.php and
PATH_BLAH\library\Zend\Validate\ with all the normal stuff
```

It's sort of hard to guess what might be wrong.

I'd be much obliged for any clue that might come to your mind.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing the data through to the form?

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()
    && $form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
    // process form
}
```

Comment: This was the correct answer. Sorry I didn't get back here soon enough to post it.

Answer (score 0):

Phil Brown nailed it.

I had actually neglected to read back the post.

Head-slap here ...